# cannot resolve symbol textview

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a problem appeared after updating Android Studio to 3.3 (dec 25th version).

Each or almost each time I'm creating a new project, the error appears when i'm trying to work with TextView - it says that it cannont resolve symbol *my any object of textview class*. I tried all the ways to resolve the problem which I found in the internet (like resync project, rebuild, etc.) but the only thing that can partly help is to write the full way (android.widget.TextView) *object name*. However this is not a full solution cause an error continues sometimes. Has anybody resolved this problem after the recent updates?

I made an example app to show my pain

[JavaFileScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGptX.png)
[XMLFileScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydTTa.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include code as text rather than as image. [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

TextView textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); reinstall repository